# Comparing string value in attribute table?

Tags: qgis, query

[image: Actually its not three different fields. I have to check this in a single field][image]

I am working on QGIS. It is a line feature.

Say we have three consecutive links. If the first and the last link has the same attribute value and the centre differs, I need to select those.

Is there any query for that in QGIS?

In the below picture, there are three consecutive links. Of that, I need to select the centre linke named "B", which differs from the other two. Can I have a query for comparing the attribution of the consecutive links and highlights the name which is odd (say "B" in this case) ?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Could you add a screenshot showing the line(s) and the attribute table?

Comment: And explain a bit more the logic of the selection you aim ...

Comment: Welcome to GIS.se! Please click 'edit' and update your question with a clear example of your data.

Comment: Is it one line (=one row in the attribute table) with three fields, or is it Three lines (Three rows in the attribute table) with one field?

Comment: It is three rows with one field

Comment: Now it is clear. Perform a Selection with a filter as `"Name" != 'B'`

Comment: Its not B actually. That was an example. I want to select a line that has a different names on either side.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it with a Virtual Layer from `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer`

```
SELECT *
FROM layer_name
WHERE field_B NOT IN (field_A, field_C) AND field_A = field_C
```

Make sure to change `layer_name`, `field_A`, `field_B`, and `field_C`.

---

***Short example***

I do have 7 lines with three attributes accordingly, check below

[image: input]

The output gives only one line that follows the demand.

[image: output]

**References:**

- [SQL IN Operator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)
- [SQL WHERE Clause](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp)

Comment: Actually its not three different fields...but a single which with three names that are inconsistent which i have to select.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have three fields in your attribute table (let's call them field1, field2, and field3 for this) and you want to select features where field1 and field3 are the same but field2 is different, then you can use this expression to select them:

```
"field1" = "field3" AND "field1" <> "field2"
```

Comment: I think you need to extend it with `OR "field3" <> "field2"` since the middle must be unique, is not it?

Comment: @Taras I don't think so because that would be covered by the first statement. If field1 and field3 are equal then you only need to check if one of them does not equal field2